# Nested generator expressions behave unexpectedly

Tags: python, generator

With the following code:

```
A = [1, 2]
B = [-2, -1]
C = [-1, 2]
D = [0, 2]

ab = (a + b for a in A for b in B)
cd = (c + d for c in C for d in D)
abcd = (e_ab + e_cd for e_ab in ab for e_cd in cd)
```

The `len(abcd)` is expected to be `16`, but it is actually `4`. If I used a list comprehension instead, the problem goes away. Why is that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can only ride the generator train once, after it reaches its destination, *no more rides*. In your case, the `cd` generator is exhausted and then can't be iterated through again.

`list` objects, on the other hand, create a separate iterator object *every time* you call `iter` on them (which the `for` loop implicitly does for you):

```
print(iter([1, 2, 3]))
# <list_iterator at 0x7f18495d4c88>
```

and produce a fresh iterator you can use. This happens *any time* `iter` is invoked on it; since a new object is produced every time, you can go through lists multiple times. Multiple rides!

In short, if you *only* change `cd` to be a list (in general, the object that will be iterated through multiple times):

```
ab = (a + b for a in A for b in B)
cd = [c + d for c in C for d in D]  # list-comp instead
```

it will yield the wanted result by creating fresh iterator objects from `cd` for every element in `ab`:

```
abcd = (e_ab + e_cd for e_ab in ab for e_cd in cd)
print(len(list(abcd)))
# 16
```

of course you can achieve this by using `product` from `itertools` too but, that's beyond the point of why this happens.

Answer (score 16):

I think this is because you can only iterate over generator once. So after you looped thorough `e_cd` first time this will not produced anything on another iteration of external cycle.

Answer (score 13):

When a generator doesn't have further values to return, it raises a `StopIteration` exception. This is how they signal that they are done. Since there isn't a built-in way to reset generators, when you create a multi-stage generator from generators, it will stop at the first encountered `StopIteration` rather than causing the child generators to loop as happens with list-like objects.

[`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) can produce the desired results (repl.it [here](https://repl.it/FEmH/1)):

```
import itertools

A = [1, 2]
B = [-2, -1]
C = [-1, 2]
D = [0, 2]

ab = (a + b for a in A for b in B)
cd = (c + d for c in C for d in D)
abcd = (e_ab + e_cd for e_ab, e_cd in itertools.product(ab,cd))
```

Comment: This could also be written as `map(sum, itertools.product(A, B, C, D))`.